# What is the most efficient way to calculate $I =\int_0^1 (1-x)^{1/2}(x^3+1) $and what is the degree of the interpolating polynomial used? $

Tags: numerical-methods, approximate-integration

I have some doubts about the following exercise

**What is the most efficient way to calculate $I =\int_0^1 (1-x)^{1/2}(x^3+1)dx $  ?**

**Solution:**
Let $g(x)=x^3+1$ and $w(x)=(1-x)^{1/2}$. With a change of variable $ x = \frac{t}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$ it can be transform to an integral over $[-1,1]$ :

$I =(\frac{1}{2})^{(\frac{3}{2})}\int_{-1}^1 (1-t)^{1/2}((\frac{t}{2}+\frac{1}{2})^3+1) dt$

so now I think that I can use a Gauss-Jacobi quadrature formula with n nodes, wich is:

$\int_{-1}^1 (1-t)^{\alpha}(1+t)^\beta f(t)dt \approx \sum_{i = 1}^n w_i f(x_i) $,...(*)

where $w_i$ are the weights and $x_i$ are the nodes (zeros of the Jacobi orthogonal polynomials over [-1,1] with respect to the Jacobi weight function $(1-t)^{\alpha}(1+t)^\beta$):

and since gaussian quadrature formulas with $n$ nodes are exact up to polynomials of degree $2n -1$, it suffices to take $3\le 2n-1 \iff n\ge 2$ nodes, so n=2 nodes is enough

**My questions are**

1. **Supposing my solution is ok, and this is indeed the most efficient way, if with n=2 nodes the formula is exact, what is the degree of the  interpolating polynomial that is used to have an exact formula?**
   There is something I am misunderstanding since I arrive to a contradiction:
   If I just use  2 nodes as found, it means I use an interpolating polynomial of degree 1, right?  But since the regular part of the integral $I$ which is $g(x) $ is a polynomial of degree 3 and the interpolating polynomial of a polynomial is the polynomial itself, so it must have degree 3, right?   Does it make sense to interpolate a polynomial with another of lower degree?
2. W**hy is this the most efficient way compared to for instance a Newton-Cotes formula or a composite formula?** I think efficiency must be understood as a compromise between fewer number of function evaluations and maximum accuracy

Comment: With Beta functions, you can do it exactly. With numerical interpolations of sufficient degree after the substitution $y=\sqrt{1-x}$, you can again so it exactly.

Comment: @J.G.  Thanks for your answer, The anwer must be with numerical methods: newton-Cotes, composite rules or Gaussian formulas.Is what  you are suggesting is the gauss-Jacobi formula?

Comment: If you're allowed the aforementioned substitution so the integrand becomes a polynomial, basically any numerical method is exact if it samples the integrand at enough values in the integration range.

Comment: The actual interpolant has the form $a(x)p_n(x) + b(x)$, where $p_n$ is the relevant Jacobi polynomial of degree $n$ and $a$ and $b$ are polynomials of degree smaller than $n$. For $n = 2$, this polynomial has degree 3.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I am not sure about the form of the interpolant you are giving, From what I have read, $f(t) $ in the formula (*) above is replaced with an interpolating polynomial, so that each weight $w_i $is the integral of a fundamental lagrange polynomial times the weight function , and using the zeros of the Jacobi polynomials we have the interpolating polynomial This is what I now about the construction of the Gauss-Jacobi formula.

Comment: Now f(t) in the problem has degree 3, so with  4 nodes the polynomial would be the same as f(t). but using the property of the gaussian formulas, I can use 2 nodes, and the formula should be exact up to polynomials of degree 2(2)-1=3. My question is if for this to happen must  the polynomial used be different from f(t) and of degree 2?